# Insert values from multidimensional array to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm really quite new to PHP and trying to learn it.
Right now I am solving a more difficult task...

I have form with some repeating fields (not all fields are repeatable).
I'm getting this output from whole form:

JSON:

```
{
    "material": [
        {
            "reference": "11",
            "mnozstvi": "25",
            "level": "1"
        },
        {
            "reference": "56",
            "mnozstvi": "88",
            "level": "2"
        },
        {
            "reference": "44",
            "mnozstvi": "123",
            "level": "1"
        }
    ],
    "pozice": "581",
    "poznamka": "Test",
    "cas": "1619965495",
    "skladnik": "7"
}
```

Decoded to array:

```
Array
(
    [material] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 11
                    [mnozstvi] => 25
                    [level] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 56
                    [mnozstvi] => 88
                    [level] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 44
                    [mnozstvi] => 123
                    [level] => 1
                )

        )

    [pozice] => 581
    [poznamka] => Test
    [cas] => 1619965495
    [skladnik] => 7
)
```

All I want to do is insert these values into one table in MySQL database.
One row for each material and add other field values (pozice, poznamka, cas, skladnik) to each row.

So each row will be: reference, mnozstvi, level, pozice, poznamka, cas, skladnik

I know that will be probably easy to you, but I'm totally lost...

Many thanks for your answers and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreach loop for material key and then use insertion as below:

```
$collection = array
(
    [material] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 11
                    [mnozstvi] => 25
                    [level] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 56
                    [mnozstvi] => 88
                    [level] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => 44
                    [mnozstvi] => 123
                    [level] => 1
                )

        )

    [pozice] => 581
    [poznamka] => Test
    [cas] => 1619965495
    [skladnik] => 7
);

foreach ($collection['material'] as $materialData) {
  //here you can use variables as below.
  echo $materialData['reference'];
  echo $materialData['mnozstvi'];
  echo $materialData['level'];
  echo $collection['pozice'];
  echo $collection['poznamka'];
  echo $collection['cas'];
  echo $collection['skladnik'];
  // you can use variables as above shared syntax and can write your sql insertion code.
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks!! Working great! I have a lot to learn and be aware of data structure.

Comment: Answer accepted, upvoted but I have no enough reputation for upvotes, but its recorded ;-)